# How can I post data to a server using JS widget using JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

In a JS widget I need to post data to a server, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONP http://json-p.org/ is only meant for get requests from a remote domain, so it seems like you can't post data to a server using JSONP.

You may try using other alternatives like jquery PostMessage plugin.